# How can I call the Wiki REST Api from an Azure DevOps extension?

Tags: azure-devops, azure-devops-rest-api, azure-devops-extensions

The [Add a dashboard widget](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/extend/develop/add-dashboard-widget?view=azure-devops#part-2-hello-world-with-azure-devops-services-rest-api) tutorial explains how to call the work item REST API using a `VSS.require("TFS/WorkItemTracking/RestClient")`d rest client.

I want to do the same, but for the **Wiki** Rest API. There certainly is a [scope](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/extend/develop/manifest?view=azure-devops#scopes) for this: `vso.wiki`.

However, I cannot find the equivalent of `"TFS/WorkItemTracking/RestClient"` for wiki. Maybe it is as simple as `"TFS/Wiki/RestClient"`, but even if it was, what are the names and parameters of the functions I can use? I don't find that documented anywhere, and I don't want to have to figure that out by trial-and-error, each time publishing a new extension and seeing if it works.

And looking at [REST Clients](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/extend/reference/client/rest-clients?view=azure-devops), there does not even seem to be a Wiki Rest Client.

So **how can I access the Wiki Rest API from an Azure DevOps extension?** Is there perhaps an example somewhere, that google has been successful in hiding from me?

---

N.B. I do know about the [REST API Specs](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/vsts-rest-api-specs/blob/master/specification/wiki/6.0/httpExamples/pagesBatch/GET_wiki_pageBatch_WithPageViews.json), but the mapping to REST client is not self-evident and apparently.

I stumbled upon [Azure DevOps Web API clients and contracts](https://github.com/microsoft/azure-devops-extension-api/blob/master/src/Wiki/WikiClient.ts), however, a brief grep revealed it does not contain the latest and greatest (pre-release) "pagesBatch" feature, and I did not find a relevant branch / tag either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The wiki rest api documents for azure-devops-extension-api can be found [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/javascript/api/azure-devops-extension-api/wikirestclient)

You can also check the restful api for wiki [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/wiki/attachments/create?view=azure-devops-rest-5.1).

Check [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/?view=azure-devops-rest-5.1#client-libraries) to discover the client libraries for azure devops service rest api in different coding languages.

Hope above helps.

Comment: Thanks Levi. Your first link is basically the processed result of my last link - it too does not have the latest (6.0) features, e.g. pagesBatch. I've created a [separate question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/59537592/709537) for this.